# Why is my JComboBox returning null?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

Note: This is a shortened version of my actual code, but pretty much the same in terms of structure. I basically cut out the panel connecting to component code and panel connecting to frame code.

On a *Display.java*, I have the following. Note that I did not add any listener to the `targetEnvironmentComboBox`. Not sure if that can be a problem:

```
public class Display extends JFrame {

    private static JButton executeButton;
    private static JComboBox<String> commandOptionsComboBox, targetEnvironmentComboBox;

    //getters
    public static JButton getExecuteButton()    {   return executeButton;               }
    public static JComboBox<String> getCommandOptionsComboBox()    {    return commandOptionsComboBox;      }
    public static JComboBox<String> getTargetEnvironmentComboBox()      {   return targetEnvironmentComboBox;   }

    public Display() {
          super("Display");
          setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          commandOptionsComboBox = new JComboBox(commandOptions.toArray());
          commandOptionsComboBox.addActionListener(new CommandListener());

          executeButton = new JButton("Execute");
          executeButton.addActionListener(new CommandListener());

          targetEnvironmentComboBox = new JComboBox(targetEnvironments.toArray());


        //main method that gets executed at the start of program
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Display();

        }
  }
```

On a separate *CommandListener.java*, I have the following:

```
 public class CommandListener implements ActionListener {

JButton executeButton = Display.getExecuteButton();
JComboBox<String> commandOptionsComboBox = Display.getCommandOptionsComboBox();
JComboBox<String> targetEnvironmentComboBox = Display.getTargetEnvironmentComboBox();

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource() == executeButton) {
        System.out.println("HGello world");
        executeCommand(event);

    }else if (event.getSource() == commandOptionsComboBox) {
        System.out.println("commandline");
        disableUnusedComponents(event);
    }
}

private void disableUnusedComponents(ActionEvent event) {
     **JComboBox<String> targetEnvironmentComboBox = Display.getTargetEnvironmentComboBox();**
     String command = (String) commandOptionsComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    switch(command) {
          case "-duplicate":
            targetEnvironmentComboBox.setEnabled(false);
            targetEnvironmentComboBox.setVisible(false);
            break;
          default: break;
     }
```

My question is that when I get the `targetEnvironmentComboBox` in the `commandListener` class right before the `actionPerformed()` method, it throws a **Null Pointer Exception**. If I remove that I get the `targetEnvironmentComboBox` in the `disableUsedComponents()` method where the **, it was able to successfully get the `combobox`.

Also if I execute the `executeButton` listener, it was able to get references to all the components in the `CommandListener` class, but if I execute the listener for the `getCommandOptionsComboBox`, it returns null for `executeButton` and `targetEnvironmentComboBox`.

Anyone can explain why this is the case?

Secondly, I know this is probably not the best implementation. Any suggestions on things I can change to follow better practice?

Comment: I don't fully understand all of your code yet, but I notice you're accessing the `JComboBox` through a static method, but only initializing it when the constructor is called. That seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: You have a super convoluted way of setting up access to these UI elements, which is redundant, hard to follow and obviously, going terribly wrong. Simple solution - have two separate listeners for the two different components you want to respond to. And then get access to the ui element strictly from the event.

Comment: Oh and additionally, if you make your event handler an inner class, you can dispense with the static instance variables and the static accessor entirely so that entire class of problems you're hitting goes away

Comment: @resueman yes but I call the display constructor on the main method (I added that code back), so it shouldn't be the reason for the problem right?

Comment: @pvg when you are mentioning two separate listeners, you are saying that I should have 2 separate listener class? I am not as worry about the solution as I am more interested in what is causing the problem.

Comment: @shaung two listener classes make the code simpler. and using inner classes (anonymous ones, if you prefer) and making the child components instance vars of display makes the entire mess of initialization you have go away. you don't need the statics, you don't need the ivars on the listener, you don't need the static accessor methods. the fundamental problem is you have made a fragile, complicated initialization and access setup that is completely unnecessary and leads to mistakes.

Comment: @pvg I agree with the two listener class, but I was told that separating the view and controller is the best practice. By using a inner class/anonymous class would I be going against that practice?

Comment: @shuang no. Listeners are not controllers. The anon inner class is appropriate here since it introduces a coupling that actually exists. What you have now decouples things that are actually coupled and makes a mess of it in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `null` because the `targetEnvironmentComboBox` doesn't get initialized until *after* you try to access it in `CommandListener`. When a new `CommandListener` is created, it reads the `targetEnvironmentComboBox` and stores it to a local variable. And look at where you create the `CommandListener`:

```
//Creating CommandListeners, which take the reference to targetEnvironmentComboBox (null)
//Although targetEnvironmentComboBox is later set to a usable value, the local copies still
//have the null reference which is assigned here
commandOptionsComboBox.addActionListener(new CommandListener());
executeButton = new JButton("Execute");
executeButton.addActionListener(new CommandListener());

//initializing targetEnvironmentComboBox, which is still null (the first time at least)
targetEnvironmentComboBox = new JComboBox(targetEnvironments.toArray());
```

If you put `Display.getTargetEnvironmentComboBox()` inside the method, it doesn't take a copy of the reference until it's needed, at which point it's been properly initialized.

An easy fix, although not the right one, is to initialize it first:

```
targetEnvironmentComboBox = new JComboBox(targetEnvironments.toArray());

commandOptionsComboBox.addActionListener(new CommandListener());
executeButton = new JButton("Execute");
executeButton.addActionListener(new CommandListener());
```

A better solution is to use proper encapsulation, and pass in what you need to access the correct objects in a constructor to the `CommandListener`s. I'd propose modifying your `CommandListener` class with something like this:

```
public class CommandListener implements ActionListener {
    JButton executeButton;
    JComboBox<String> commandOptionsComboBox;
    JComboBox<String> targetEnvironmentComboBox;

    public CommandListener(JButton executeButton,
                           JComboBox<String> commandOptionsComboBox,
                           JComboBox<String> targetEnvironmentComboBox){
        this.executeButton = executeButton;
        this.commandOptionsComboBox = commandOptionsComboBox;
        this.targetEnvironmentComboBox = targetEnvironmentComboBox;
    }

    /* The rest of your code */
}
```

Then passing those field in (making sure you're passing non-null values), and doing away with all the static variables (or refactoring to something more manageable).

Comment: I did not try your fix yet, but what you are saying make sense. I would like to have proper encapsulation, but if I remove the static from the components won't I need to intialize a new display in the commandlistener class? And if I do that, the display in the main method won't be the same display in the commandListener so the variables won't be the same. Can you show an example of how to do 'proper encapsulation'?

Comment: @shuang I added an example of how I think it should be done. The approach I would use would be passing in everything you need in a constructor to the `CommandListener` - either a `Display` instance or, like I showed, just the Swing components you need. Basically, instead of exposing everything to everyone with `static`s, you directly give the necessary values to new objects when you create them.

Comment: @resueman an anon inner class for the listeners makes all of that redundant initialization, well, redundant. it can just access the ivars of the enclosing instance of `Display`. It makes it even harder to screw up because you can't even pass the wrong thing to the constructor.

Comment: @resueman I see. This is good but the issue is that I have a lot of combobox, and buttons and it's going to be the commandlistener constructor very ugly. One more question is, should I be initializing a new commandlineListener object for each component in the Display or should I create only one commandlineListener and use it among all my components?

Comment: @shuang If it's really complicated then you can pass in just the `Display` to the constructor and call accessors on it like you are now (removing all the `static`s, and making sure the object is correctly initialized beforehand). For the second question, whichever one leads to the most clear code. I suspect one listener for each will be best (and you might want to use inner classes (anonymous or not) as [pvg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5087125/pvg) recommends, especially if the listeners are very tightly-coupled with the `Display` itself).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Using `static` methods to access an instance, use  encapsulation and access it through `setters and getters`.

The only way you can get the **INSTANCE** of your `targetEnvironmentComboBox` object is by having the instance of your Display also "pointing" at the same *space in memory*, try:

```
public JComboBox getComobo(){
   return [your_object];
}
```

instead of:

```
public static JComboBox getTargetEnvironmentComboBox(){
  // your code . . .
}
```

and pass the `Display` instance through the `CommandListener` constructor.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simplified example of how to set this sort of thing up in a way that both greatly reduces the amount of boilerplate code and is essentially immune to the kind of initialization problem you're encountering. This is also a fairly typical approach in Swing UI code and, in fact, one of the drivers for the introduction of anonymous inner classes.

```
public class Display extends JPanel {

    private JButton executeButton;
    private JComboBox<String> commandOptionsComboBox;

    public Display() {

        executeButton = new JButton("Exec");
        commandOptionsComboBox = new JComboBox<>();

        executeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Action performed");
                commandOptionsComboBox.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
```